# Swift - UIImage not shows up in TableViewCell (shows when clicked and disappear when other cell is clicked)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I created a tableview with custom cell.

Storyboard looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, I put check symbol at the right side of the cell.
I assigned the custom cell class as follow:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var checkImage: UIIMageView!
}
```

And in the tableview class, i have function that states:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

The weird thing is... when the cell is clicked the check mark shows up. And when other cell is clicked, the check mark disappears and only shows up at the selected cell.
I really have no clue what is going on here..
I tried answers from similar questions but none of them worked.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Show us your `didSelectRowAt` method. Also, you are aware that you can do `cell.accessoryType = .checkmark` for the built in checkmark?

Comment: Oh wow... let me try

Comment: Jesus what was my past 2 hrs.. Thank you. You resolved what i need. But hmm why wasn't it working anyway.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is to be able to select multiple cells.

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Adding the line above should solve your problem.
However, why don't you use the accessory Checkmark? You can use even the Basic UITableViewCell and select the acc[image]
You only need to set `cell.accessoryType = .checkmark` or `cell.accessoryType = .none`.

Comment: Well there is more thing to implement and what i want to do is not selecting multiples.. and yes, i could have used accessory, but i just didn't know it exists until 5 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

[image: Just select multiply selection]

Just select `multiply selection` for tableview